# Extension Development: How to access "no internet" page in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Maybe it's silly question!
I'm creating Google Chrome extension to modify the built-in dino game that appears when there is no internet connetion.
But I got the error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot access contents of the page.
> Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective
> host.

I tried adding `chrome://*/` or `chrome://dino/` to host permission but no luck.

Comment: chrome://dino/ works fine for me

Comment: I got error: *Invalid scheme for 'host_permissions[chrome://dino/]'.*